# Cannot login with private key using SSH

Tags: linux, mac, ssh, openssh

I have a linux server, a Mac, in linux server I have a user `sato`

copy `sato/.ssh` to local Mac

```
$ scp -r root@XXX:/home/sato/.ssh sato_ssh
```

then

```
$ ssh -i sato_ssh/id_rsa sato@XXX

sato@XXX: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

How can I login?

Comment: What did you expected the first command to do?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl copy .ssh folder in server to local Mac

Comment: But why would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't login because you copied your public key from the server. SSH security doesn't work because you have the same key on client and server, but because you have matching private (on your client) and public (on your server) keys. Your public key is a bit like a padlock that you can reproduce at will and can open with the private key that you are the only one to have (and that you must keep as safe as possible). People can steal the padlock, but without the key there is no use for it.

So you have to find the private key you use to login on the server, and copy it to whatever system you want to use as the client (alternatively you can regenerate a key pair...). Note that SSH is picky about the permissions on the SSH directory and its contents (shouldn't be writable by anyone but you).